# How can I build a Ruby interpreter with only needed libraries?

Tags: ruby

How can I build a Ruby interpreter with only Core API (exclude Process class) and without standard library?

It should not include irb or anything else. A pure interpreter with necessary components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have no idea how you can build it, but matz (the creator of ruby) published a project that provides a minimal version of ruby called mruby: https://github.com/mruby/mruby/